# pyrun - Relative import fails

Tags: python-3.x

I have the following folder organization.

```
pyrun-pb
├── folder-1
│   ├── common.py
│   ├── data.py
│   └── test-run-1.py
└── test-run-2.py
```

The file `test-run-1.py` uses `runpy.run_path` with success contrary to `test-run-2.py`. Here is a terminal session.
What am I missing?

```
> python /path/to/pyrun-pb/folder-1/test-run-1.py
{'test': 'example'}
> python /path/to/pyrun-pb/test-run-2.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/path/to/pyrun-pb/test-run-2.py", line 8, in <module>
    data = run_path((THIS_DIR / 'folder-1') / 'data.py')
  File "//path/to/python3.9/runpy.py", line 288, in run_path
    return _run_module_code(code, init_globals, run_name,
  File "//path/to/python3.9/runpy.py", line 97, in _run_module_code
    _run_code(code, mod_globals, init_globals,
  File "//path/to/python3.9/runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/path/to/pyrun-pb/folder-1/data.py", line 3, in <module>
    from common import CVAR
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'common'
```

---

### Codes

```py
# test-run2.py

from pathlib import Path
from runpy   import run_path

THIS_DIR = Path(__file__).parent

data = run_path((THIS_DIR / 'folder-1') / 'data.py')

print(data["XTRA"])
```

```py
# test-run1.py

from pathlib import Path
from runpy   import run_path

THIS_DIR = Path(__file__).parent

data = run_path(THIS_DIR / 'data.py')

print(data["XTRA"])
```

```py
# data.py

from common import CVAR

XTRA = {
    'test': CVAR,
}
```

```py
# common.py

CVAR = "example"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a "dirty" working solution.

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from pathlib import Path

import os
import sys
from runpy import run_path

THIS_DIR = Path(__file__).parent

FILE_CALLED = (THIS_DIR / 'folder-1') / 'data.py'

dirpath = os.fspath(str(FILE_CALLED.parent))
sys.path.insert(0, dirpath)

data = run_path((THIS_DIR / 'folder-1') / 'data.py')

sys.path.remove(dirpath)

print(data["XTRA"])
```